# c++ vector::erase with class object iterator not erasing vector member

Tags: c++, class, vector, iterator, erase

I know that this question is similar to others, but I looked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4645705/vector-erase-iterator) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18083130/vector-erase-function-in-for-loop-is-not-erasing-vector-of-classes-properly) and neither of these solved my problem. Everything I have been able to find says that the following code should work. 
The vector I use for testing has elements with names superman, batman, and spiderman. I can't remove any more code for the example to make sense I don't think.

```
class Room{
  vector<User> users;
  users = {{superman, pass}, {batman, pass}, {spiderman, pass}};

public:
  vector<User> Room::getUsers() {return users;}
};

class User{
  string username;
  string pass;
};



    // Find the room. Once found, scan through the users
    // Once the user is found, remove them from the vector
    for(roomIt = rooms.begin(); roomIt < rooms.end(); roomIt++) {
      if (roomIt->getName().compare(roomName) == 0) {
        for (useIt = roomIt->getUsers().begin(); useIt < roomIt->getUsers().end(); useIt++) {
          if (useIt->getName().compare(username) == 0) {
            useIt = roomIt->getUsers().erase(useIt);
            const char * msg = "OK\r\n";
            write(fd, msg, strlen(msg));
            return;
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

The room object has a vector of type user. `roomIt->getUsers()` returns the vector of users in a room. The innermost if statement doesn't do anything, however. To debug, I have a vector of 3 Users. When using gdb, I can see that `useIt = roomIt->getUsers().erase(useIt)` causes the iterator to move from the second element in the vector to the third element. However, the vector does not change. There were 3 elements beforehand, and there are 3 elements afterwards as well.

Comment: What does `getUsers()` return? i.e [mcve] please

Comment: Sorry, not definitely answerable without complete code. My guess would be that `getUsers()` returns a copy instead of a reference.

Comment: My crystal ball is telling me you're returning a copy of the vector, and not a reference to the original vector.

Comment: You should consider to use https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase%E2%80%93remove_idiom

Comment: Works on my machine.  I had to add the missing code.  The code I added must not have the bug that your code has.  Can you provide a minimal, complete, verifiable example?

Comment: @Eljay I've edited the code to add the bare minimum functions and objects that I can provide. Are the other users correct in stating that I am using a copy, not a reference, which is creating the problem?

Comment: @StephenBurns  Yes, you're returning a copy of the vector instead of a reference.  Surprised your program didn't die due to invalid iterator usage.

Comment: Do not put the "`Room::`" on a member declaration inside the class definition. It is incorrect C++ syntax, although MSVC allows it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [user2328447 speculated in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49762949/c-vectorerase-with-class-object-iterator-not-erasing-vector-member#comment86541589_49762949) your `getUsers` is returning by value, not reference. So every single time you call it, you get a completely unrelated `vector` (same values, but stored separately); even your loop construct is wrong (it's comparing the `.begin()` from one copy of the `vector` to the `.end()` of a separate copy).

If you want to be able to mutate the instance's `vector` from the caller, you must return a reference, changing:

```
vector<User> Room::getUsers() {return users;}
```

to:

```
vector<User>& Room::getUsers() {return users;}
            ^ return reference, not value
```

Comment: Additional suggestion: Decide whether code which uses class `Room` should be able to modify the user list via `getUsers()`. If no, make the declaration `const vector<User>& getUsers() const;`.  If yes, implement both that `const` version (so code can still view users from a `const Room&`) and also a `vector<User>& getUsers();`.

Comment: @aschepler: As written, they definitely need to be able to modify the user list. But yes, providing a version returning a `const` reference is a good idea for cases where the caller only needs to see the user list, not `erase` from it.